# Report viewer in wpf and selection formula

Tags: wpf, reportviewer

I have a WPF application that I would like to present SQL Server Reporting Services sql 2008 reports in. I understand we have to use host widow control and then in report viewer control. I want to use remote processing mode. 
My code sample is :
I have added namespaces:

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using Microsoft.Reporting;
using Microsoft.ReportingServices;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

My XAML:

```
xmlns:wfi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
xmlns:wfr="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms"

Title="ReportHost" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <wfi:WindowsFormsHost Height="100" Margin="39,27,39,0" Name="winFormsHost" VerticalAlignment="Top" >

        <wfr:ReportViewer x:Name="rptViewer" ProcessingMode="Remote"   />  

    </wfi:WindowsFormsHost>

</Grid>
```

Code:

```
rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = 
  new Uri("http://mymachine-:8080/ReportServer_myreports");
rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath="/Reports/mytestreport.rdl";
rptViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

My question is that how how can I set selection formula in microsoft report viewer control [like crystal report]. Or miscroft provided any this else which behave like selection formula in crystal reports.

And when I run the code it show only report viewer in host window control but not the report data in window.

Please some one provide me all step list, Which I have to fallow to get required result with sample code.

Quick response will be appricated.

Answer (score 0):

For the path to the report, leave off the .rdl extension:

`rptViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath="/Reports/mytestreport";`

Sorry, I'm not familiar with Crystal Reports's selection formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Using ReportViewer in remote mode is painful in several ways, one of which is that you have to code everything as parameters - you can't just set the selection formula and be done with it.

I recommend you switch to using LocalReport.  All you have to do is retrieve the RDL from the server, execute the queries, and set the DataSources property.  The main advantage is you really don't need the server at all and you don't need to worry about server configuration changes breaking your application, but you also get better performance (usually) and much more flexibility.

If you are using LocalReport, you can embed your reports in your .exe or .dll using ReportEmbeddedResource, or you can have them as files alongside the .exe or .dll and use ReportPath, or you can have them on the server and download them to the temp directory for use.

When using LocalReport it is trivial to do arbitrary selection:  Just add some LINQ.  In other words, replace this:

```
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(
  new ReportDataSource("Sales", GetSalesData()));
```

with this:

```
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(
  new ReportDataSource("Sales", GetSalesData().Where(d => d.Amount > 10)));
```

The only reasons I can think of where you might be required to run the reports on the server and deal with the pain and inefficiency are: 1. If the client can't get to the data any other way due to security lockdown, and 2. If a huge data set is retrieved and processed down to a small set and the client is small or remote.  In either of these cases your only option is to manually add parameters to the RDL and then use those parameters to filter your data.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Ray Burns,

According to our discussion I concluded that:

1) If I used remote processing mode then I have to pass all the parameter on which I have to filter the record.

2) If I used local processing mode then In C# code I have to set data source of the report.

But

As I am using microsoft Reporting services sql 2008. I have designed the reports in SQL server Business intellegence Studio and their I have written queries / or calling stored procedure and also set the data source their. So its means that repoorts should contain only design and all data base related things will be handle in C# code?
And all the client machine have the reports locally, is that good way?